# Load rsa private key from integers and convert to PEM format or RSA structure in openssl to sign message

Tags: openssl, rsa, pem

I have the `public exponent`(e), `modulus`(n) and `private exponent`(d) of a RSA key, how can I convert them to a RSA key in `PEM` format or a RSA structure defined in openssl?

I want to sign text with RSA private key with openssl, either in `C` code or `openssl` utility is acceptable.

I've searched the internet, there're quite some posts that can extract parameters from the `PEM` key, but failed to find useful informations on how to convert them back to PEM with `C`. Seems that this is not a common scenario...

edit: Sorry that the title is kind of misleading, my ultimate purpose is to use it to sign message(as stated in the description)

Comment: *"...  or openssl utility is acceptable"* - if you want help on using the OpenSSL commands, then you should ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is a programming and development Q&A site. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) and [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) are sites that help you with using commands.

Comment: @jww , actually I want to implemet it by c program, but if there's an openssl command to work out this, I can make my program by referencing openssl's source code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RSA math only requires `n` and `d` to implement signing. Furthermore, OpenSSL's implementation also only requires `n` and `d` to do signing. You can set these values directly in the RSA structure. This example only shows an example of "...sign text with RSA private key with openssl ... in C code" and ignores your PEM query.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

static void printerrors() {
    char errbuf[1024];
    while (1) {
        unsigned long error = ERR_get_error();
        if (error == 0) {
            break;
        }
        ERR_error_string(error, errbuf);
        fputs(errbuf, stderr);
    }
    fflush(stderr);
}

static void sign(RSA *rsa, const char *message) {
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    if (!EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(pkey, rsa)) goto err;
    EVP_MD_CTX *ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    if (!EVP_DigestSignInit(ctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, pkey)) goto err;
    if (!EVP_DigestSignUpdate(ctx, (const void * ) message, strlen(message))) goto err;
    size_t siglen;
    if (!EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctx, NULL, &siglen)) goto err;
    unsigned char *signature = malloc(siglen);
    if (signature == NULL) goto err;

    if (!EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctx, signature, &siglen)) goto err;

    for (int i = 0; i < siglen; i++) {
        printf("%02x", signature[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(signature);
    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

    return;
err:
    printerrors();
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int BITS = 1024;
    const int PUBLIC_EXPONENT = 65537;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    RSA *rsa = RSA_generate_key(BITS, PUBLIC_EXPONENT, NULL, NULL);

    RSA *rsa2 = RSA_new();
    rsa2->n = BN_dup(rsa -> n);
    rsa2->e = BN_dup(rsa -> e);
    rsa2->d = BN_dup(rsa -> d);

    RSA_print_fp(stdout, rsa2, 0);
    sign(rsa2, "Sign me, please");
    RSA_free(rsa2);
    RSA_free(rsa);
}
```

The other values normally associated with the private key, `p`, `q`, etc. are not strictly necessary. If present they can be used to speed up private key operations including signing by taking advantage of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Also, they can be easily derived from `n`, `d`, and `e` if desired: see for example [section 8.2.2 (i) of the Handbook Of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap8.pdf).

Comment: It works, thanks very much! I used to think openssl may need more arguments to perform the rsa sign operation (as listed in @ice13berg , there're many other fields besides `n` `d` `d`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have everything required for an RSA key.  Specifically, you don't have the prime numbers required to generate the RSA key, `p` and `q`.

RSA keys require the original prime integers used to calculate `n`, `e`, and `d`, so only having them is not enough to generate an entire RSA key.

See the documentation [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ASN1_generate_nconf.html) on ASN1 encoding for more information.

EDIT: @GregS: `n` and `d` are not enough for a public-private keypair, as `e` is actually a part of the keys `(n,e)` and `(d,e)`.

From [here](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem), you can see that an RSA Private Key requires both `prime1, p` and `prime2, q`, while the Public Key only requires `(n,e)`.

> RSA Private Key file (PKCS#1)
>   The RSA private key PEM file is specific for RSA keys.

```
RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      version           Version,
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
      privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
      prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
      prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
      exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
      exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
      coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
      otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
    }
```

Comment: All that is needed is `n` and `d`.

Comment: @GregS - I've seen certs in the wild that use non-standard `e` (i.e., not 3, 17, or 65535). In these cases, you can't guess `e` is a well known value.

Comment: @jww: To sign, which is what the OP requested, only n and d are needed.

Comment: Thanks for this point, actually I found that there're so many parameters in the RSA structure, so I'm not sure if I can sign the message with only `n` `d` `e` -- luckily it work.